# With FirebaseAuth, can I generate an ID token without a logged-in user?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, firebase-admin, bearer-token

I'm trying to customize my Firebase Functions server using the code sample here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint. In my Angular client, I have succeeded in getting a fresh idToken by manually signing in a 'background' super-user:

```
constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
...
this.firebaseAuth.auth
  .signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(
    environment.firebaseSuperUser,
    environment.firebaseSuperUserPass
  )
  .then((credential: UserCredential) => {
    credential.user.getIdToken().then(token => {
      this.storeTokenInDb(token)
      this.callApi(token)
    })
  })
```

This is required because the Auth middleware on my server is restricting access to all functions based on this token value:

```
admin
  .auth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(decodedIdToken => {
    if (decodedIdToken.uid === 'D1akN6puCwYbkUMJAExTqOEx5fg4') {
      console.log('Token matches admin user')
      return next()
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to match token with admin user.')
      return next('403 Unauthorized')
    }
  })
```

However, this strikes me as a problematic approach long-term, because I don't want to log-in and log-out my super user every time I want to refresh his token. So my question is, is it possible to get an ID token for a user without logging that user in?

I was hoping for a function like this: `FirebaseAuth.getIdToken({uid: 'D1akN6puCwYbkUMJAExTqOEx5fg4'})` that returns an ID token corresponding to any user, whether they're logged in or not. I would like to generate a Firebase ID token for any user any time.

The reason I want this is because my client is sending HTTP GET requests to my Functions server as a "super user" with full access to my `api/endpoints` (through Bearer token authorization) and write access to the DB:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'D1akN6puCwYbkUMJAExTqOEx5fg4'"
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm approaching this in the wrong way, but right now I have an ordinary logged-in user, and a second super-user firing off all my API requests. Bottom line is I want to restrict access to my `api/endpoint` routes to the super user, exclusively. Those routes should only be accessible internally, to the client sending the request. Hope this makes senses, and I'm all ears to a better approach.

Comment: Why are you using a second user account, instead of just giving the necessary permissions to the ordinary user accounts? You can use custom claims to control permissions on individual users in a fine-grained way.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think this is what I needed to hear, and do believe this is possible, just need some advice. Basically, I want to prevent the logged-in user from seeing `mysite.com/api/endpoint` when they visit it in their browser (or send a request via Postman or Curl, for example). So while the user is barred access, the app client on the other hand does need to access it (via `mysite.com` as a referrer). So while a user is logged in, the content should be served to them indirectly through the app, but direct access should be forbidden. That's the reason for the original decision.

Comment: but now that I think about it...the user can't send a request via the browser, Postman or Curl without a Bearer token, it'll just reply `Unauthorized`. And the ID token is "secret", it can only be generated by my client. Is there any way for a user to create their own ID token? If not, it seems like my API is secure after all, so long as I restrict DB writes and API calls to authenticated users. That seems to take care of my concerns above.

Comment: All signed in users get their own ID token. You can check if the ID token has a specific claim in the backend, and throw a 401 if not. Then you just need to make sure your "app client" has this claim on its ID token.

Comment: great, will take a deeper look at claims. thanks friend.

Comment: You're welcome. I've written [this article](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/firebase-introducing-bulk-user-export-and-custom-claims-e0187344c8ee) about this feature. You might find it useful.